# C program for xor operation, operators entered by scanf

Tags: c, scanf, bitwise-xor

I wrote a small program to run a bitwise XOR operation. The values shall be inserted in the command line:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char x = 0, y= 0;

    printf("This program performs a Bitwise XOR operation of two chars\n");
    printf("Enter a value for the first variable: ");
    scanf("%i",&x);

    printf("Enter a value for the second variable: ");
    scanf("%i",&y);
    printf("1. Value = %i\n2. Value = %i\n",x,y);

    y ^= x;

    printf("Result XOR-Operation = %i", y);
    printf("\nResult in hex: 0x%x", y);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program its returns 0 for the first value...

Output of the command line:

```
1 This program performs a Bitwise XOR operation of two chars
2 Enter a value for the first variable: 10
3 Enter a value for the second variable: 5
4 1. Value = 0
5 2. Value = 5
6 Result XOR-Operation = 5
7 Result in hex: 0x5
```

I'm using gcc compiler and run it in windows command line. Do I may have to use a pointer? Couldn't find something about this topic...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understand correctly, your question is not about the result of the `^=`, but about the output of the `printf()` before it?

Comment: `%i` expects a pointer to `int` and you are passing a pointer to `unsigned char`.  That is bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%i` format specifier is expecting a `int *`, but you're passing it a `unsigned char *`.  Because the latter points to a smaller datatype, `scanf` will attempt to write past the bounds of the variable it want to write to.  This causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You want to use the `hh` modifier (for `char`) to tell `scanf` to expect the proper pointer type as well as the `u` format specifier for `unsigned`.

```
scanf("%hhu",&x);
...
scanf("%hhu",&y);
```

Comment: Shouldn't we also change the types of `x,y` to `signed char`, since `%i` expects a signed argument, or else use `%hhu`?

Comment: @NateEldredge I believe there is latitude in signed vs. unsigned, but yes `%u` would be preferable.  Updated.

Comment: Sure, it will work fine either way on typical platforms.  I'm just being pedantic.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thank you!
I didn't think about it, because the second value was always returned correctly. Well, I should probably refresh my basics knowledge...